# UITableViewCell IBAction not working in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, ios7

What I'm facing is I've developed code in Swift. It has a some custom cells and UIButtons in them. The buttons are IBOutlet Connections with properties in their respective Cells and actions against them are bound in the same classes. Now the Question is that it works perfect in iOS 8. But I don't know what's wrong with iOS 7 whenever I touch the button, the complete cell is tapped and Tableview's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called. What I've done so far is

- Check `.userInteractionEabled` for parent views and cell and changing it's values
- Remove buttons and re add them as found on different forums but no luck
- Checked Tableview's delegate methods `numberOfSections`, `numberOfRowsInsection:` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and changed their return types to NSInteger and CGFloat as found on stackoverflow Against a Question.

Has anyone else faced this issue and found solution so far?

**Edit**

- Checked by reseting target action of UIButton after setting values to cell. No Luck

Comment: Give custom actions to button using addTarget when you create your tableview cell.

Comment: I've done this in awakefromNib. Lemme try in layOutSubviews

Comment: Just put that code when your create your cell using subviewing in tableview or somewhere. Just put the action method below that.

Comment: Checked in layoutsubviews as well as after setting values to cell. No luck

Comment: static NSString *simpleprice = @"Price";
        
        price = (PriceCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleprice];
        
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PriceCell" owner:self options:nil];
        
        price = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
[price.btnPrice addTarget:self action:@selector(buyPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: http://s29.postimg.org/ip38q9stj/Screen_Shot_2014_12_22_at_12_17_22_pm.png

Comment: Not opening the page

Comment: Create a chat room and let me know your problem there.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/9hb09klr7/9eb323c8/

Comment: Please post the image in your question or in chat room. Some things are blocked contents so can't be seen.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/G54Xthe.png

Comment: But your cellforrow method is on tableviewcell or on your viewcontroller's tableview methods? I can't see the code for subviewing your tableviewcell. I am getting confused on that one.

Comment: Definitly it's in Viewcontroler's class and Subviewing mean adding UIButton in cell? If so, then it's from Storeyboard and cell has property rightBUtton retained IBOutlet with storeboard

Comment: Can you please come in chat? I'll show you what I have done in my project and make you understand better.

Comment: Do you check that your `rightButton` isn't nil at the moment, when you add action-target? Also I see you call some `reset()` function of cell. Maybe this function clear buttons target?

Comment: No it's not nil. And it's working perfectly for iOS 8. if it would be nil. It should not work for iOS 8 either.

Comment: And reset just changes titles of buttons.

Comment: Do you need `didSelectRow` event ?

Comment: yes I do and implemented.

Comment: Can you just share this part of project code and nib?

Comment: It's in storeyboard. Not in nib. And part of code of what?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your problem. Its running fine for me. Please see my code below.

In TestTableViewController.swift

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell

       // Configure the cell...

        cell.testButton.addTarget(cell, action: "testButtonClicked", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

       return cell

    }

       override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        NSLog("didSelectRowAtIndexPath called")

    }
```

In CustomCell.swift

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var testButton: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Initialization code

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state

    }

    func testButtonClicked() {

        NSLog("Button Clicked")

    }

}
```

When I clicked on the button it logs "Button Clicked" and when clicked on cell it logs "didSelectRowAtIndexPath called". You might be doing something wrong in reset() function or second last function.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the code below in my app and it is working fine.

Do not try to code on your custom tableview cell.

You can get values of that cell in your viewcontroller.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        static NSString *simpleprice = @"Price";

        price = (PriceCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleprice];

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PriceCell" owner:self options:nil];

        price = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        [price.btnPrice addTarget:self action:@selector(buyPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return price;

 }
```

Hope this helps you. This works for ios7 and ios8 also.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

i have faced such issue after long time digging it, i found root cause and it was in **Cell XIB**

**what i did as Before:**

i)  First i have added CustomCell `.h` and `.m`.
ii) After then i have added **XIB** by new file option, you have noticed,
   there is option like **"View"** that's i have selected and add in to the bundle. Bind it with my `CustomCell.h`.

**Solution :**

i)   Add **XIB** by new file option, Choose **View** in user interface. 
ii)  In XIB you can see view at left panel. delete that view.
iii) Drag and drop there UITableViewCell from User Interface panel. After complete this steps **XIB** would be seen similar something like below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your cell.button `Action target to self`, and copy your button action method into viewController class (.mm) file where the UITableView is available.